# Multiple Choice Reaction python (discord.py)

Tags: python, discord

I'm trying to do a multiple choice button / reaction in discord using python (discord.py) -- something similar to the image below:

[image: Multiple choice reaction discord example image]

For example when it reacts to 2️⃣, that shows page 2, when it reacts to 3️⃣, that shows page 3 ...
Could anyone help me, please?

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

class Wiki(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self,bot):
        self.bot=bot

    #commands
    @commands.command(name="wiki",aliases=["w"])
    async def wiki(self,ctx):
        page1=discord.Embed(
        title='Page 1/3',
        description='Description1',
        colour=discord.Colour.orange()
        )
        page2=discord.Embed(
        title='Page 2/3',
        description='Description2',
        colour=discord.Colour.orange()
        )
        page3=discord.Embed(
        title='Page 3/3',
        description='Description3',
        colour=discord.Colour.orange()
        )
        pages=[page1,page2,page3]

        message= await ctx.send(embed=page1)

        await message.add_reaction('1️⃣')
        await message.add_reaction('2️⃣')
        await message.add_reaction('3️⃣')
        
        emoji=""
        if emoji=="1️⃣":
            await message.edit_message(message,embed=pages[0])
        if emoji=="2️⃣":
            await message.edit_message(message,embed=pages[1])
        if emoji=="3️⃣":
            await message.edit_message(message,embed=pages[2])       

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Wiki(bot))
```

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  You have to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.

Comment: ["Can Someone Help Me?" is not a valid SO question]( https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question). This usually suggests that what you need is time with a local tutor or walk through a tutorial, rather than Stack Overflow. Best of all, each tutorial will teach you a collection of related techniques, rather than merely solving the immediate problem.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the documentation for [wait_for](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=wait_for#discord.Client.wait_for), which is how you should treat this kind of case. I won't spoonfeed you the code though, you should give it a fair shot yourself first.

Also, discord.py already has something built-in for embeds that change pages automatically based on reactions called [menus](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord-ext-menus), so it'll probably be easier to just use that instead of re-implementing it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question.

I know it's not the best answer, but it works XD.
Any suggestion will be well accepted. Thank you all so much for your help.

```py
import asyncio
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
class Wiki(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self,bot):
        self.bot=bot
    
    #commands
    @commands.command(name="wiki",aliases=["w"])
    async def wiki(self,ctx):
        first_run = True
        while True:
            if first_run:
                page1=discord.Embed(title='Page 1/3',description='Description1',colour=discord.Colour.orange())
                first_run=False
                msg = await ctx.send(embed=page1)

                reactmoji = ["1️⃣","2️⃣","3️⃣"]
                
                for react in reactmoji:
                    await msg.add_reaction(react)

            def check_react(reaction, user):
                if reaction.message.id != msg.id:
                    return False
                if user != ctx.message.author:
                    return False
                if str(reaction.emoji) not in reactmoji:
                    return False
                return True
            
            try:
                res, user = await self.bot.wait_for('reaction_add', check=check_react)
            except asyncio.TimeoutError:
                return await msg.clear_reactions()

            if user != ctx.message.author:
                pass
            elif '1️⃣' in str(res.emoji):
                print('<<1️⃣>>')
                await msg.remove_reaction("1️⃣",user)
                await msg.edit(embed=page1)
            elif '2️⃣' in str(res.emoji):
                print('<<2️⃣>>')
                page2=discord.Embed(title='Page 2/3',description='Description2',colour=discord.Colour.orange())
                await msg.remove_reaction("2️⃣",user)
                await msg.edit(embed=page2)
            elif '3️⃣' in str(res.emoji):
                print('<<3️⃣>>')
                page3=discord.Embed(title='Page 3/3',description='Description3',colour=discord.Colour.orange())
                await msg.remove_reaction("3️⃣",user)
                await msg.edit(embed=page3)
            

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Wiki(bot))
```